# getting a null error of a body (while it's not) when colliding in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

P.s. This is gonna be long so I suggest you to drink your morning coffee while reading this

Here's the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body developer.io.aimzballz.Blocks.getBody()' on a null object reference 
at void developer.io.aimzballz.Gameplay.beginContact(com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact) (Gameplay.java:336)
at void com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.beginContact(long) (World.java:985)
at void com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(long, float, int, int) (World.java:-2)
at void com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(float, int, int) (World.java:689)
at void developer.io.aimzballz.Gameplay.render(float) (Gameplay.java:231)
 at void com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render() (Game.java:46)
at void developer.io.aimzballz.Main.render() (Main.java:34)
at void com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10) (AndroidGraphics.java:459)
at void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun() (GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
 at void android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run() (GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

and here's the part where the error shows up

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l;i++){
        for (int x = 0; x < k;x++){
             if ((contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == ballz[i].getBody() &&
                    contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == blocks[x].getBody()) ||
                    (contact.getFixtureB().getBody() == ballz[i].getBody() && contact.getFixtureA().getBody() == blocks[x].getBody())) {
                blocks[x].decreaseScore();
                if (blocks[x].getScore() <= 0) {
                    handler.removeObject(blocks[x]);
                    final Body toRemove = blocks[x].getBody();
                    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            world.destroyBody(toRemove);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weird part is ... this error sometimes shows up , sometimes no and not only that, I also scheduled a task by `Timer` and it sometimes executes the task sometimes no.
Time to clear some stuff here , `ballz[]` and `blocks[]` are game objects (classes extending an abstract class called `GameObject`) and if you can't get a sense for what my code means I can explain but for now I want to show you another thing

```
private void translateBlocks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < k;i++){
        blocks[i].getBody().setLinearVelocity(0, 3);
    }
    Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopBlocks();
        }
    } , 0.75f);
}
private void stopBlocks(){
    for (int i = 0; i < k;i++){
        blocks[i].getBody().setLinearVelocity(0,0);
        created = false;
    }
    k = k + rnd.nextInt(2) + 1;
    diffOfK = k - diffOfK;
    createBlocks(k , diffOfK);
}
```

while `k` is number of blocks existing and `createBlocks` is as it sounds like
 when an object from `ballz` collide after creating the blocks I get the null error that I showed at the beginning
 that's everything I hope I cleared up my problem... if I missed any thing or if you have any questions about my code feel free to comment about it
**EDIT**
Handler class

```
public class Handler {

LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

public void render(ShapeRenderer renderer){
    for (GameObject tempObject : object) {
        tempObject.render(renderer);
    }
}
public void dispose(){
    for (GameObject gameObject : object){
        gameObject.dispose();
    }
}
public void textRender(SpriteBatch batch){
    for (GameObject gameObject : object){
        gameObject.textRender(batch);
    }
}

public void addObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.add(object);
}
public void removeObject(GameObject object){
    this.object.remove(object);
}
```

}
here's a [video](https://youtu.be/71Q1yMQ-7Nk) showing what happens

Ok I want to clarify something,  my problem isn't removing bodies or objects , I'm getting an error after creating new blocks and when any `ballz` collide with any body ( even if it's not the blocks ) and plz guys the watch the video to understand what I'm saying and By the way , Score stands for number on blocks **that u can see in the video**

Comment: copy paste the stacktrace here... the screenshot is not scrollable... :)

Comment: Is `translateBlocks` being run after you delete the blocks? You're probably trying to set the velocity of a body that was deleted.

Comment: @Midnightas no blocks are deleted until there score is below 0 and this error is captured with score > 0 soo

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ done

Comment: Could you please attach this function?
`handler.removeObject(blocks[i]);`

Comment: @avix what do u mean by "attach"

Comment: @HeshamHaikal show us :)

Comment: @avix showed u the whole class ;)

Comment: @HeshamHaikal Is there any relationship of `handler` 's `object` to `blocks`? and How do you update their state after you destroy one of Box2d body? If this is a case, I might have an answer.

Comment: @haxpor `handler`'s `object` is just a Linked List of GameObjects generally  whether it's `blocks` or `ballz`...... before I destroy one of bodies I call `handler.removeObject` and that removes the game object from the List

Comment: I don't think the body could be destroyed when contact happened, so your app crash when you intended to destroy a object at `beginContact`. You should register the objects in the array, and destroy all the registered objects once before or after `world.step()` function.

Comment: @HeshamHaikal ok. Could you please also show the code when you update `l` variable? Also you commented in @avix answer that it should be `blocks[x].decreaseScore()`. Could you also update your question to reflect the latest change?

Comment: @Tokenyet `world.step` is running on main Runnable while `world.destroy` is on another Runnable

Comment: Break your if statement up in your begin contact, ie get each body before the if statement and assign it to a variable. Then set break points and run your code in debug mode. This will show you that your Blocks object is null. The only reason that it is null is because it has not been assigned, or has been assigned incorrectly. Check your construction of your objects and collisions.

Comment: @BinaryMonkL I tried breaking up but it's even getting a null error when I check if the bodies are null or no  .... it's like saying "Just die "

Comment: That is because the null pointer is happening on the object you are trying to get the body from. I am pretty sure you are not assigning something in your own code. This is not a box2d problem. So in your breakpoints, dont check if the body is null, check if the thing you are getting them from is null

Comment: nulls in that collection you fetch your things from

Comment: I solved my problem , I'll post an answer about it .... it was simple and thanks @BinaryMonkl

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make sure that fixtures are not null. I'm almost 100% sure that you encounter on null block while for iterations.

I will propose this kind of solution:

```
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) 
    {
        Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
        Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

        if(fixA == null || fixB == null) return;

        if(fixA.getUserData() instanceof Ball || fixB.getUserData() instanceof Ball)
        {
            Fixture ballFixture = fixA.getUserData() instanceof Ball ? fixA : fixB;
            Fixture blockFixture = fixA.getUserData() instanceof Ball ? fixB : fixA;

            Block block = ((Block)blockFixture.getUserData());

            block.decreaseScore();
            //and all other functions
        }

    }
```

I assume that elements in ballz and blocks arrays are of different types, if they are not, make them be. 
Of course to make my code work you have to set user data of fixtures when creating them.

```
body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(ball);
```

The same with **blocks**.

You should also consider using some Lists instead of arrays.

Comment: well I changed `blocks[i].decreaseScore()` to `blocks[x].decreaseScore()` ( it was supposed but I didn't notice ) and I did what u showed in here but still getting the error ....... and how can I use lists ? what's difference ?

Comment: What does Score mean there? You have to decrease amount of iterations.
And actually the fastest way is using List. 
Switch your ballz and blocks tables to List (you are already using it in Handler class).